# TDD in Legacy Code - Breaking 'Constructor' dependencies

Tags: java, refactoring

In a JAVA application, I have the following class:

```
public class PathEditor extends DocumentListBase {
    public PathEditor(Paths paths, Frame frame) {
        super(frame);

        // Some logic is being executed here.
    }
}
```

The class is using some complicated inheritance, but all the involved classes to be able to instantiate a `PathEditor` are listed below.

**Paths**

```
public class Paths {
}
```

**Frame**

```
public class Frame extends DocumentListItemBase {
    public Frame(DocumentBase parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

**DocumentListItemBase**

```
public class DocumentListItemBase extends DocumentBase {
    public DocumentListItemBase(DocumentBase parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

**DocumentBase**

```
public class DocumentBase {
    public Document _document;

    public DocumentBase(DocumentBase parent) {
    }

    public Document getDocument() {
        return this._document;
    }
}
```

**DocumentListBase**

```
public class DocumentListBase extends DocumentBase {
    public DocumentListBase(DocumentBase parent) {
        super(parent.getDocument());
    }
}
```

**Document**

```
public class Document extends DocumentBase {
    public Document(DocumentBase parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to add a function to the `PathEditor` which I would like to add using a TDD approach.
You might see the problem, I cannot create a `PathEditor` in a UT context, since it depends on concrete types.

Note that the concretes types does some logic in their constructor such as calling a DB, so it's not suitable to add them in a 'UT' context.

Obviously, this class has to be refactored to allow TDD approach, but the class does NOT contain any tests.
What's the preferred approach to make this class testable, using the smallest possible changes so that I'm sure that I'm not breaking anything that the constructor does?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the existing code does not have tests, your first job is to add tests before modifying that code. This will form a baseline for your changes, ensuring you do not introduce regression.
2. None of the concrete classes shown are `final`, so for example, `Paths` and `Frame` can be sub-classed as testing mocks, if that makes things easier. It matters less that the dependencies are concrete, so long as the dependencies are injected and are extensible.
3. If constructors rely on dependencies which are *not* injected and you wish to test such classes without invoking those dependencies, you may be forced to refactor those classes. Start with #1 and write (at least integration) tests before refactoring.

Comment: So it means that I must add tests for the constructor of the absolute 'base' class first to the top, until I reach the Path Editor class before I can start adding a feature to it using TDD. Is that a correct assumption?